# Maximum integer index in PHP array

Tags: php, integer, int, 32bit-64bit

The following PHP code

```
<?php
  $x[5076021987]=1234;
  var_dump($x);
?>
```

produces the following result on `32bit` architecture:

```
array(1)
{
   [781054691]=>int(1234)
}
```

but correct result on `64bit` architecture:

```
array(1)
{
   [5076021987]=>int(1234)
}
```

Is there anything I could do to make it work properly even on `32bit` arch? Note that converting the long integers to string is no solution in my case. Thank you.

Comment: Use a string instead of a literal integer. This has nothing to do with its use as array key. The integer was already chomped before the array assignment.

Comment: As I wrote, converting to string is no solution for me. Furthermore, $x=5076021987+1 properly calculates as 5076021988 on 32bit so I really do not understand why PHP works ok on calculation but wrongly on array index.

Comment: 5076021988 is just a lucky float that prints as integer: use var_dump($x). And you haven't really explained **why** you can't use a string. (Arrays store keys internally as strings anyway.)

Comment: I think you using windows server

Comment: Nope, using 32bit ubuntu

Comment: You could use some hashmap to store your long-something pairs, but since array itself is a hashmap, i dont know how many good hashmap libraries in php are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking through everything, [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) says

> The key can either be an integer or a string.

Check the `Syntax section`.

So it turns out that you **have to** use `String` as an index. There is definitely no other go.

If you show exactly how you get these indices or some more information of what exactly you're trying to do, the I could suggest something else.

<strike>Only possible solution is to convert the index to `float`</strike>

```
<?php
    $index = 5076021987*1.0;
    $x[$index]=1234;
    var_dump($x);
?>
```

This is probably not gonna work. Because, `php` is going to convert it back to `integer` when using it as an index. I don't have 32 bit PC so cant test it sorry.

If that does not work, You're only other hope is

```
<?php
    $index = 5076021987+0.1; // or even 5076021987*0.1
    $x[$index]=1234;
    var_dump($x);
?>
```

And then use it some how.

Other than this, you don't have any other option (other than converting to string, which you don't prefer).

Comment: Just use `(float)` instead if you're converting something to float. `$index = (float) 5076021987`

Comment: yes, but it will be reconverted to int if when used as an index. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Neil, your example makes no sense to me. Assigning $x[]=1234 just adds the value at the next available index, like in $x[0]=1234 if $x is undefined yet. Anyway, using $x[$index] as you probably intended to suggest doesn't fix it.

Comment: yea..I figured that out..I've mentioned that..you could try the second one..if you show more code, or show what exactly your trying to do, maybe I could give better suggestions

Comment: Your second solution is the same, the index appears as 781054691

Comment: Using *0.1 produces array(1) { [507602198]=>int(1234) } ... this is obviously correct since 507602198 is 10 times smaller number which fits inside 32bit integer.